# Filter for the List<List<String>>

Tags: java, list

I am trying to write a method that would filter the duplicate inputs in a list of lists of Strings. The problem is that by duplicates I mean also the lists that have the same elemets buts in a different order. So I would like that if the input list is :

```
[["1", "2","3"], ["2","1","3"],["3","1","2"]]
```

it would return only

```
[["1","2","3"]]
```

I tried to do something like:

```
public List<List<String>> filter (List<List<String>> list){
    List<List<String>> filteredList = new LinkedList<>();
    filteredList.addAll(list);
    for(List<String> i:list){
        for(List<String> j:list){
            if (!i.equals(j)&&i.containsAll(j)){
                filteredList.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return filteredList;
}
```

but it would remove too much cause it would still iterate through the whole original list and would find that element "a" is duplicate of element "b" and vice versa. On the other side when I try to do that on the same list (without a temp) I get ConcurrentModificationException cause I can't modify and iterate over the same collection at the same time. Adding the list to a Set would not solve the issue because they are not exact duplicates (.equals would return false). Is there any possible solution to achieve at?

Comment: As I mentioned above it would not work, because those elements are not equal according to .equals() method

Comment: If you iterate in reverse order you might prevent concurrent modification exception. for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--) and in general smaill tip: sort second dimension lists before than taking any action

Comment: What should your list return? some examples of input and output?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you start by sorting each list, which makes it easier to identify when they're equal. Once that's done, an easy way to eliminate duplicates is to add them to a `Set`.

One approach could look like this:

```
List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
lists.add(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
lists.add(Arrays.asList("2", "1", "3"));
lists.add(Arrays.asList("3", "1", "2"));

lists.forEach(Collections::sort);
Set<List<String>> collect = lists.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(collect);
```

Results in the output `[[1, 2, 3]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Class for the inner List with a equals-method that does what you need. You could use a set for this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all to avoid ConcurrentModificationException - do a new list and copy to it only values iterated on the original list, that were not yet copied before.

Second of all You can create a map/set that would contain values that were already copied to check for duplicates. To make this work, You need to sort the inner list before putting the values into the map/set and before checking if they are already there

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to implement a Set, a set is already part of the java API, here is the link [Set (Java API)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)